# Best practice database structure preserving order data

Tags: data-structures

I would like to find out a best practice for the following use case (very simplified here):

I have three tables:

Table "orders":

- id
- order_date

Table "order_products":

- id
- order_id
- product_id
- amount

Table "products":

- id
- name
- supplier_id

Table "suppliers":

- id
- name

Obviously these tables are connected and everything is fine.

Now let's say an order is already completed. 
Afterwards product data is changed or another supplier is taking over a product that is already in a completed order.

What would be the best practice to preserve data for an already completed order? And as I said, the above structure is very simplified. In reality there are 30 connected tables.

I was thinking about two ways so far:
- Save all the data (products, suppliers, ...) in the order table in a JSON data type field
- Have a versioning system in place that saves every record changes in all connected tables so that e.g. the order_products table can refer to a product_id + record-version-combination

Both ways look like overkill to me though

Comment: What database system are you (planning to) work with? Some may have certain features that make things significantly easier. E.g. SQL Server has temporal tables so you could make `Products` temporal and then always be able to inspect its contents as they were at `order_date`.

Comment: Interesting. We will use MySQL (with PHP)

Comment: If the supplier id changes, is it still the same product? If you want the ability to re-create an order some time in the future, then you can't be changing the supplier id. You have to create a new product if you change suppliers. Yes, this affects your system quite a bit. Nobody said that database was easy.